# Wagtail: wrong filepath when I compile the project

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to upgrade Wagtail from 1.13 to 2.0 and I get this error when trying to migrate:

```
RuntimeError: Model class wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

And log is:

```
[...]
 File "C: \ Program Files \ Python36 \ lib \ site-packages \ wagtail \ wagtailcore \ blocks \ field_block.py", line 16, in <module>
    from wagtail.wagtailcore.rich_text import RichText
  File "C: \ Program Files \ Python36 \ lib \ site-packages \ wagtail \ wagtailcore \ rich_text.py", line 10, in <module>
    from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
  File "C: \ Program Files \ Python36 \ lib \ site-packages \ wagtail \ wagtailcore \ models.py", line 54, in <module>
    class Site (models.Model):
  File "C: \ Program Files \ Python36 \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ base.py", line 118, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I have previously installed everything necessary for the update and I have passed the script to rename the changed fields.

In the log you can see that the path that should point to the core actually points to the old version (wagtailcore) instead of "core":

```
C: \ Program Files \ Python36 \ lib \ site-packages \ wagtail \ wagtailcore \ models.py
```

I think all the problems come from here, how do I do to django to look in the correct folder?

UPDATE:

I tried to uninstall with pip uninstall wagtail but some folders weren't deleted:
[result post uninstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVPPs.png)

And command throws this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 550, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\wagtail\\tests\\testapp\\migrations\\__pycache__\\0005_customrichblockfieldpage_customrichtextfieldpage_defaultrichblockfieldpage_defaultrichtextfieldpage.cpython-36.pyc' -> 'C:\\Users\\plata\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-v6wl_qyt\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\wagtail\\tests\\testapp\\migrations\\__pycache__\\0005_customrichblockfieldpage_customrichtextfieldpage_defaultrichblockfieldpage_defaultrichtextfieldpage.cpython-36.pyc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 75, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 683, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 224, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 280, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 564, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\plata\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-v6wl_qyt\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\wagtail\\tests\\testapp\\migrations\\__pycache__\\0005_customrichblockfieldpage_customrichtextfieldpage_defaultrichblockfieldpage_defaultrichtextfieldpage.cpython-36.pyc'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `wagtailcore` app folder doesn't exist at all in Wagtail 2.0's codebase, so it looks like you still have the old version of Wagtail installed. Try running `pip uninstall wagtail`, and confirm that the `C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail` folder has been properly deleted before running `pip install wagtail==2.0.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I uninstalled wagtail the folder still has the version 1.13.1 folders not deleted.I don't dare erase them by hand.
Shoud I delete it by force?

When I deleted it, console retunrs a error:
[..]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\plata\\[...]\\migrations\\__pycache__\\0005_customrichblockfieldpage_customrichtextfieldpage_defaultrichblockfieldpage_defaultrichtextfieldpage.cpython-36.pyc'